# Apache Airflow - how to use SFTPSensor to detect FOLDER changes and only download new files

Tags: airflow

if I have something like this:

```
check_SFTP = SFTPSensor(task_id="check_SFTP", 
                        sftp_conn_id="My_company",
                        path="/in/",
                        file_pattern="*",
                        poke_interval=15, 
                        timeout=60*5,
                        dag=dag 
                        )
```

it's looking for a pattern of a specific file.   My problem is that my folder is not a 1-file folder and is an archive of files. I'm looking to find out whether or not NEW files are there and report a list of files to obtain.  it looks like this:

file-01012024.zip
file-01022024.zip
file-01032024.zip

and builds on that, and doesn't delete for 90 days.  I have this variable: `int(Variable.get("TAM_File_Number"))`. which looks like this: `01012024`.

So in this case, I need to SFtp files newer than Jan 1 2024, then update the variable.

How can I change the Sensor to do that? and tell me the newest file name so I can set the new variable date?

Thanks!